# Read xsl variable inside javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath

Simply i want to read an xsl variable inside javascript function, i tried many forms but no one works!

1-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var strMSG="<xsl:value-of select='//ListExamQuestions.LeaveExamConfirmMsg'/>";
function confirmClose(){
return strMSG;
}
</script>
```

2-

```
<xsl:variable name="strMSG"> 
<xsl:value-of select='//ListExamQuestions.LeaveExamConfirmMsg'/>
</xsl:variable>

<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmClose(){
return {$strMSG};
}
</script>
```

3-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var strMSG="<xsl:value-of select='//ListExamQuestions.LeaveExamConfirmMsg'/>";
<![CDATA[
function confirmClose(){
return strMSG;
}
]]>
</script>
```

Note:`<xsl:value-of select='//ListExamQuestions.LeaveExamConfirmMsg'/>` returns a valid text when used inside normal XSL code

Any help is appreciated,thanks.

Comment: just dump the text into a hidden element using xslt and use the DOM from js to get the text back.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like you want to read the result of an XPath from inside Javascript. See if your Javascript has an XPath evaluation library available.